# How I can make appear a custom widget (WordPress)

Tags: php, wordpress, widget

In my WordPress website, I added a custom widget with help of this plugin: https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-post-type-widgets/

I want to show that widget on my archive page with PHP.

I went to https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_widge but didn't get what I use to make that widget appear in website. I still do not understand how to use it or what name, class, etc. I should use in website to make it appear.

It's created by an option in theme so not getting how to get it's class or ID
but in Appearance->widget code is listed below.

```
<div class="widgets-holder-wrap closed">
    <div id="sidebar-18" class="widgets-sortables">     <div class="sidebar-name">
        <div class="sidebar-name-arrow"><br /></div>
        <h2>Custom Post Type - course <span class="spinner"></span></h2>
    </div>
            <div class="sidebar-description">
        <p class="description">course</p>
    </div>
    <div id='widget-61_custom-post-type-categories-4' class='widget'>   <div class="widget-top">
<div class="widget-title-action">
    <button type="button" class="widget-action hide-if-no-js" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="screen-reader-text">Edit widget: Categories (Custom Post Type)</span>
        <span class="toggle-indicator" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    </button>
    <a class="widget-control-edit hide-if-js" href="/wp-admin/widgets.php?editwidget=custom-post-type-categories-4&#038;sidebar=sidebar-18&#038;key=0">
        <span class="edit">Edit</span>
        <span class="add">Add</span>
        <span class="screen-reader-text">Categories (Custom Post Type)</span>
    </a>
</div>
<div class="widget-title"><h3>Categories (Custom Post Type)<span class="in-widget-title"></span></h3></div>
</div>

<div class="widget-inside">
<form method="post">    <div class="widget-content">            <p><label for="widget-custom-post-type-categories-4-title">Title:</label>
    <input class="widefat" id="widget-custom-post-type-categories-4-title" name="widget-custom-post-type-categories[4][title]" type="text" value="asdf" /></p>

 <p><label for="widget-custom-post-type-categories-4-taxonomy">Taxonomy:</label><select class="widefat" id="widget-custom-post-type-categories-4-taxonomy" name="widget-custom-post-type-categories[4][taxonomy]"><option value="category">Categories category</option><option value="employees_category">Employees Categories employees_category</option><option value="faq_category">Faq Categories faq_category</option><option value="news_category">News Categories news_category</option><option value="portfolio_category">Portfolio Categories portfolio_category</option><option value="testimonial_category">Testimonial Categories testimonial_category</option><option value="photo_album_category">Photo Album Categories photo_album_category</option><option value="wp_cc_tax_country">Country wp_cc_tax_country</option><option value="course-category" selected='selected'>Course Categories course-category</option><option value="expert-field">Expert fields expert-field</option><option value="internship-category">Internship Categories internship-category</option><option value="country-cost">Countries for Cost country-cost</option><option value="application-basket">Applications Baskets application-basket</option><option value="scholarship-category">Scholarship categories scholarship-category</option><option value="entry-requirement">Entry Requirements entry-requirement</option><option value="awarding-level">Awarding levels awarding-level</option><option value="intake">Intakes intake</option><option value="study-mode">Study Modes study-mode</option><option value="status">Statuses status</option><option value="course-keyword-taxonomy">Course Keywords course-keyword-taxonomy</option></select></p>
    <p><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" id="widget-custom-post-type-categories-4-dropdown" name="widget-custom-post-type-categories[4][dropdown]" />
    <label for="widget-custom-post-type-categories-4-dropdown">Display as dropdown</label><br />

    <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" id="widget-custom-post-type-categories-4-count" name="widget-custom-post-type-categories[4][count]" checked='checked' />
    <label for="widget-custom-post-type-categories-4-count">Show post counts</label><br />

    <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" id="widget-custom-post-type-categories-4-hierarchical" name="widget-custom-post-type-categories[4][hierarchical]" checked='checked' />
    <label for="widget-custom-post-type-categories-4-hierarchical">Show hierarchy</label></p>
</div>  <input type="hidden" name="widget-id" class="widget-id" value="custom-post-type-categories-4" />
<input type="hidden" name="id_base" class="id_base" value="custom-post-type-categories" />
<input type="hidden" name="widget-width" class="widget-width" value="250" />
<input type="hidden" name="widget-height" class="widget-height" value="200" />
<input type="hidden" name="widget_number" class="widget_number" value="4" />
<input type="hidden" name="multi_number" class="multi_number" value="" />
<input type="hidden" name="add_new" class="add_new" value="" />

<div class="widget-control-actions">
    <div class="alignleft">
        <button type="button" class="button-link button-link-delete widget-control-remove">Delete</button> |
        <button type="button" class="button-link widget-control-close">Close</button>
    </div>
    <div class="alignright">
        <input type="submit" name="savewidget" id="widget-custom-post-type-categories-4-savewidget" class="button button-primary widget-control-save right" value="Save"  />            <span class="spinner"></span>
    </div>
    <br class="clear" />
</div>
</form> </div>
```

Comment: Can you add your code to your question?

Comment: Helo ventiseis, I have added code, please checkm Thank you